# MathJax how to know whether all operations in queue have been executed completely?

Tags: queue, mathjax

I have to perform some action after all the processes that were pushed in the queue have been executed completely.
I have a function which is creating a div element.This function is queued using mathjax queue.Suppose wrap is an element created in this function.Now i am returning wrap.innerHTML from outside the function.What is happening here is that the control is reaching return wrap.innerHTML statement before the process queued for creation of this element is complete.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Clearly explain your question?

Comment: i have a function which is creating a div element.This function is queued using mathjax queue.Suppose wrap is an element created.Now i am returning wrap.innerHTML.What is happening here is that the control is reaching return wrap.innerHTML before the process queued for this element is complete.

Comment: QUEUE.Push(function(){
    mespan.id = MathOutput;
    mespan.setAttribute("class", "mathEditor");
    mespan.setAttribute("contenteditable","false");
    mespan.setAttribute("tex",Tex);
    $('.text').each(function(i){
      $(this).attr('value',$(this).val());
    });
    mespan.setAttribute("edithtml",$('.formula_container').html());
    target = document.getElementById('mathdiv').children[1];
    target.setAttribute("contenteditable","false"); wrap = document.createElement('div');
mespan.appendChild(target.cloneNode(true));
wrap.appendChild(mespan.cloneNode(true));});return wrap.innerHTML;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to return `wrap.innerHTML` from the function that performs the `QUEUE.Push()`, since `wrap` isn't created until the queued function runs, and that may not be until later.  Whatever needs to use `wrap.innerHTML` will have to run as a callback instead.  You could call it from the function that has been `Pushed()`, or `Push()` the callback onto the queue so that it runs after that function is finished.